# How to get modified date of GTLDriveFile in Google Drive in iOS in swift?

Tags: swift, google-drive-api

I am integrating google drive in my project of swift.
Integrating via google drive integration guide line, but My projects needed to access all the details like modified date,created date etc.
But unable to find in the 
all these details.
Using following code :

```
if let modifiedDate = file.modifiedByMeTime{
    print_debug(modifiedDate)
}

if let modifiedDate = file.sharedWithMeTime{
    print_debug(modifiedDate.milliseconds)                
}
```

How to get modified date of GTLDriveFile in Google Drive in iOS in swift?

Comment: I'm still learning Swift, but it seems that [`GTLDriveFile`](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_drive_file) has `modifiedTime` (which is a [GTLDateTime](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_date_time) object that has `NSDate`)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
 let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
   query.pageSize = 100
   query.q = path
    query.fields = "files(id,name,mimeType,modifiedTime,createdTime,fileExtension,size),nextPageToken" 
 // u want to specify what all details want as response.//

    service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, files, error) in

            if let filesList : GTLRDrive_FileList = files as? GTLRDrive_FileList {

            if let filesShow : [GTLRDrive_File] = filesList.files {
            print("files \(filesShow)")
                    for ArrayList in filesShow {
                    let name = ArrayList.name
                    let mimeType = ArrayList.mimeType
                    let id = ArrayList.identifier
                    let folder = (mimeType as NSString?)?.pathExtension


                    let creationTime = ArrayList.createdTime?.date // modified time
                    let modifiedTime = ArrayList.modifiedTime?.date //createdTime

                    }
            }
         })
```